# Python - error during formatting string in subprocess call

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

my script in python 3.8 must run an external command and use some variables, and is:

```
print('\nProvisiong VM with ansible')
print(url)
print(vm_id)
output = subprocess.run(["ansible-playbook", "-i", "%s:22%s,", "-e", "ansible_user=ubuntu", "playbook.yml" % (url, vm_id)]) 
print(output)
```

I've insert the `print(url)` and `print(vm_id)` to see if they exist, the result is:

```
Provisiong VM with ansible
11.22.33.44
113
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./launch_vm.py", line 136, in <module>
    output = subprocess.run(["ansible-playbook", "-i", "%s:22%s,", "-e", "ansible_user=ubuntu", "playbook.yml" % (url, vm_id)]) 
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The syntax seems correct to me ... maybe the problem is with the subprocess call?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the formatting to the correct string, i.e. `"%s:22%s,"`:

```py
output = subprocess.run(["ansible-playbook", "-i", "%s:22%s," % (url, vm_id), "-e", "ansible_user=ubuntu", "playbook.yml"])
```

If you *really* want to do a common formatting of all the strings, you need to write them as one. Thus this does the same thing:

```py
output = subprocess.run(("ansible-playbook -i %s:22%s, -e ansible_user=ubuntu playbook.yml" % (url, vm_id)).split())
```

**Also note:** I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but the additional comma after `%s:22%s` looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: Maybe add an example of good use of f-strings? It seems a nice addendum and does the job gracefully

Comment: The comma after `%s:22%s` is required, thanks!!